# Database query return: Check if a parameter is an array or an object

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When trying to log into this app using php and mysql, the `Authorization failed` error used in the app is displayed. When reading the `php_error.log` it displays:

> [05-May-2019 03:31:51 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: result in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iReporter/api.php on line 43 [05-May-2019
>   03:31:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an
>   object that implements Countable in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iReporter/api.php on line 43

Log in function

```
//login API
function login($user, $pass) {

// try to match a row in the "login" table for the given username and password
$result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username='%s' AND pass='%s' limit 1", $user, $pass);

//Line 43
if (count($result['result'])>0) {
    // a row was found in the database for username/pass combination
    // save a simple flag in the user session, so the server remembers that the user is authorized
    $_SESSION['IdUser'] = $result['result'][0]['IdUser'];

    // print out the JSON of the user data to the iPhone app; it looks like this:
    // {IdUser:1, username: "Name"}
    print json_encode($result);
//edit
var_dump($result);

} else {
    // no matching username/password was found in the login table
    errorJson('Authorization failed');
}

}
```

This application use to let users log in seamlessly but stopped working abruptly without any changes made to the code. Even the unchanged backup files are receiving the same error. How can the code be be changed to allow users to log in successfully?

Update: index.php. The main file the app accesses functions

```
switch ($_POST['command']) {
case "login":
    login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']); 
    break;
```

Solved

Changed the iOS app to post the password instead of the salted password to the database as it was creating an error.

Comment: Can you check whether it fetches data from the database. make sure that it is connected to MySQL databases

Comment: @Sathiraumesh it does. It successfully shows a `username is already taken` error when an existing username is tried when attempting the register function. It also successfully displays pictures from the app's database on the app's home screen.

Comment: use this I think it may work
$rows = $result->num_rows;

if($rows>0){
}

Comment: Thank you. Where should I add it to the code?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, you are not getting the `result` value within your `$result` variable. To check for this you can use:

```
if (isset($result['result']) && count($result['result']) > 0)
```

Which first checks that the value is set.

You will also want to investigate why you aren't getting your expected result from your DB. For that, you will need to look into what is being returned in your `$result` variable, and looking for any errors that your DB querying may be returning.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It weirdly still shows the `Authorization failed` error also without any output to the error log

Answer (score 1):

You might add a `is_array` in addition to `isset()`, else access denied.

```
function login($user, $pass)
{

// try to match a row in the "login" table for the given username and password
    $result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username='%s' AND pass='%s' limit 1", $user, $pass);

    if (is_array($result) && isset($result) && count($result) > 0) {
        if (isset($result['result'])) {
            // a row was found in the database for username/pass combination
            // save a simple flag in the user session, so the server remembers that the user is authorized
            $_SESSION['IdUser'] = $result['result'][0]['IdUser'];

            // print out the JSON of the user data to the iPhone app; it looks like this:
            // {IdUser:1, username: "Name"}
            print json_encode($result);
        }else{
            errorJson('Sorry! There is a problem with $result["result"]!'); 
        }
    } else {
        // no matching username/password was found in the login table
        errorJson('Authorization failed');
    }

}
```

The error is returning since your array is not an array and is not countable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now the error log displays `[05-May-2019 05:05:26 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'count' (T_STRING) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iReporter/api.php on line 44`

Comment: Not yet. The error log says `[05-May-2019 05:33:16 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: result in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iReporter/api.php on line 44
`

Comment: when `var_dump($result);` is added to the log in function like the edited question, no output in seen in the browser when trying to access the index.php file via browser

Comment: Yeah, it was working before with `$result['result']` , it just stopped abruptly. Granted it's from 2012. Source: https://www.raywenderlich.com/2895-how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-2-2 Download is at the bottom  hehe

Comment: Ok. I see the `'Sorry! There is a problem with $result["result"]!'` Error. Thanks again. Will see what can be done...

Comment: After deleting the iOS app, redownloading it, and updating it to recommended settings in Xcode, it allows for logging in and registering, but registering can only be completed with the password `1234`. Will try to delete as many compiler warnings as possible to hopefully get back up to where it can allow for both logging in and registering.

Answer (score 1):

```
function login($user, $pass) {

// try to match a row in the "login" table for the given username and password
$result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username='%s' AND pass='%s' limit 1", $user, $pass);

$rows=$result->num_rows;
//Line 43

if ($rows>0) {
    // a row was found in the database for username/pass combination
    // save a simple flag in the user session, so the server remembers that the user is authorized
    $_SESSION['IdUser'] = $result['result'][0]['IdUser'];

    // print out the JSON of the user data to the iPhone app; it looks like this:
    // {IdUser:1, username: "Name"}
    print json_encode($result);
} else {
    // no matching username/password was found in the login table
    errorJson('Authorization failed');
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now the error log says `
[05-May-2019 05:18:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iReporter/api.php on line 44
`

Comment: can you just check whether the $result variable gets populated after the query is executed

Comment: Earlier `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` was added to the index file. When the app was run, the browser output something like `array(0)`. But now `Expected status code in (200-299), got 500` is being displayed when trying to run the app with the error reporting statements.

Comment: Updated the question with the where the log in function is used